# How to convert memory stream to string array and vice versa

Tags: vb.net, memorystream

I have a code where i want to get an stream from an image and convert the memory stream to string array and store in a variable. But my problem is i also want to get the image from the string variable and paint on a picture box.

If i use this like 
    PictureBox1.Image = image.FromStream(memoryStream)
I am able to print the picture on picture box. But this is not my need. I just want to get the image stream from file and convert the stream as text and store it to some string variable and again i want to use the string variable and convert it to stream to print the image on picture box.

Here is my Code.(Vb Express 2008)

```
 Public Function ImageConversion(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Image) As String
        If image Is Nothing Then Return ""

        Dim memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
        image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)

        Dim value As String = ""


        For intCnt As Integer = 0 To memoryStream.ToArray.Length - 1
            value = value & memoryStream.ToArray(intCnt) & "  "
        Next

        Dim strAsBytes() As Byte = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(value)
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(strAsBytes)


        PictureBox1.Image = image.FromStream(ms)

        Return value
    End Function
```

Comment: I am just curious - why do you need to convert/load the image to a memory stream in order to show it in the picture box and can't you just save the image directly to the file system and then load it using the standard methods?

Comment: Thanks for ur rply. But I know the standard methods. I just want to load the string variable in Rich text Box. Where i get like
"71 70 56 255 240 15...." (depend on the picture) the rgb value and i want to change the value manually just for experiment purpose and repack into the image, nd i want to see the change. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wouldn`t work in the way you have posted it (at least the part of recreating the image).
See this:

```
Public Function ImageConversion(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Image) As String
    If image Is Nothing Then Return ""

    Dim memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
    image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)

    Dim value As String = ""

    Dim content As Byte() = memoryStream.ToArray()
    ' instead of repeatingly call memoryStream.ToArray by using
    ' memoryStream.ToArray(intCnt)
    For intCnt As Integer = 0 To content.Length - 1
        value = value & content(intCnt) & "  "
    Next
    value = value.TrimEnd()

    Return value
End Function
```

To recreate the image using the created string you can`t use Encoding.GetBytes() like you did, because you would get a bytearray which represents your string. E.g "123 32 123" you would not get a byte array with the elements 123, 32 , 123

```
Public Function ImageConversion(ByVal stringRepOfImage As String) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim stringBytes As String() = stringRepOfImage.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim bytes As New List(Of Byte)
    For intCount = 0 To stringBytes.Length - 1
        Dim b As Byte
        If Byte.TryParse(stringBytes(intCount), b) Then
            bytes.Add(b)
        Else
            Throw new FormatException("Not a byte value")
        End If
    Next
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes.ToArray)
    Return Image.FromStream(ms)
End Function
```

Reference: [Byte.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry I can't understand this part can u explain this?

           ' Dim b As Byte
            If Byte.TryParse(stringBytes(intCount), b) Then
                bytes.Add(b)
            End If'

Comment: Assume you have changed the values inside your richtextbox to a value which can`t be converted to a byte because e.g the value is 1234 so Byte.TryParse tries to parse the value to a byte and returns true if succeeding and false otherwise. 
Maybe it would be better to throw an exception because it wouldn`t result in an valid image anymore.

Comment: Now i understand when i change a value from rtf and passed the rtf value to the function it throw an exception.

Comment: No, therefor you would need a else statement there. Byte.TryParse tries to parse the string value to a byte value. If this is not possible because it can`t be parse you should throw an exception. I have updated the code.

Comment: Thank u. But can u tell me after converting to string and displayed into rtf my string look like "71 73 70 56 57 97 125 0 127 0 247 0 0....."

But when i chnage the values between 71 to 97 it throw an exception. But after 97 if i change value 125 to rest the picture display well on picture box. I dont know is this a gif file structure and i change without knowing the format. Little bit off topic though, but can u explain me?

Comment: No, not really. Try posting an ew question so maybe an image expert can help you.